run docker command within python subprocess within GitHub runner
I am running functional tests as CI in my GitHub runner.
To properly execute my tests, I am building a docker image and running it (a slightly modified mysql container). Because I am building the container from a Dockerfile (not only pulling it from a registry), I dont use GitHub service or container capabilities (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/use-cases-and-examples/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers).
Instead I have some steps dedicated in my GH workflow to build the container and run it like this
  - name: build docker container
    run: |
      cd tests/functional/olbp/mocked_data/
      docker build --no-cache -f my_service.Dockerfile -t my_service_test:latest .
  - name: run container
    run: docker run --name my_service -d -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 my_service_test --sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
  - name: wait for MySQL to start
    run: |
      until mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 --silent; do
      echo 'Waiting for MySQL to start...'
      sleep 1
      done

Finally I am calling my functional tests (pytest) with python
  - name: run the functional tests
    run: python -m pytest tests/functional -vv -s --log-cli-level=DEBUG

This is working fine, my tests can obvisouly interract with the mysql container.
However I am struggling to interract with Docker in this context. I would like to generate a mysqldump part of my tests. So I wrote this inside my tests:
dck_exc_output = subprocess.run(
    [
        "docker",
        "exec",
        "my_service",
        "mysqldump",
        "--skip-triggers",
        "--skip-extended-insert",
        "--compact",
        "--no-create-info",
        "-uroot",
        "-psupersecret",
        "my_db",
        "my_table",
        ">",
        live_data_dump,
    ],
    capture_output=True,
    shell=True,
)

logging.debug(dck_exc_output)

It is working fine when being executed from my computer but whenever I try to get this executed inside the GH Runner (this docker command or even a simple docker version). I end up on this output (output for subprocess of a simple docker version via subprocess):
DEBUG    root:my_test.py:246 CompletedProcess(args=['docker', 'version'], returncode=0, stdout=b'', stderr=b'
Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

...
')

I already confirmed that I have same user, same permission and same env variable between the subprocess and the GH runner commands.
I cannot understand why I am receiving this output. The docker executable seems to be found (because I am receiving the helppage as if I was executing a wrong command) but it will not execute as it is doing when I run the test locally.

Are you running it on a GHA-hosted runner? Does docker version work directly from the workflow? Are you using the same version of docker locally?

Yes, a GHA self hosted runner. Docker version works perfectly directly from the flow (this is from there that I build and run the container before I start my pytest process (the one that I wish could subprocess the docker exec).

That output doesn't make any sense. It says you were attempting to run the docker version command, not the docker exec command you show in your question, but it also indicates that the command completed successfully (returncode=0)...and then shows docker's help output.

You shouldn't need Docker debugging commands to interact with the database.  Can you just subprocess.run(['mysqldump', ...])?  Then you can use the mysqldump --result-fileoption.  You can also use thesubprocess.run(stdout=...)` option to redirect the subprocess output to a (local) file without using shell redirection.

Thanks for your feebacks! Indeed the output I included is for the ‘docker version‘ subprocess. But to me it doesnt make any more sense.. why do I have a successful return code? And why is it showing the help menu whereas the command is valid? It also tells that the docker utility is found and executable (no env, or permission issue then).

Regarding calling mysqldump directly, I wish I could limit installations on the host system (my PC or the GH runner), to rather embeds everything inside Python or the container. Your proposal is still very valid to get things to work but I am curious on what's going on with these docker calls in GH Runner (and why the same script is working when being run on my machine.

You have an error in your Python code. You're attempting to use shell i/o redirection in your arguments to subprocess.run(), but (a) you're not setting shell=True and (b) you're passing in a list of arguments rather than a string.
If you want to use shell i/o redirection (like somecommand > somefile), you may only pass a single string as your argument to subprocess.run and you must set shell=True:
subprocess.run(
f'docker exec my_service mysqldump --skip-triggers --skip-extended-insert --compact --no-create-info -uroot -psupersecret my_db my_table > {live_data_dump}',
shell=True
)

If you don't set shell=True, then your command is not executed by a shell, and things like > are passed literally to the executing command.

(Remember that shell=True comes with some security risks.  If live_data_dump includes punctuation like a semicolon, this construction can run any caller-specified command at all; and if the caller knows they can run docker commands, they can use this to take over the entire host system.)

Absolutely. I would normally say, "never use shell=True and handle i/o redirection in Python instead", but I wasn't sure I wanted to get into that here.

Right, this helped me! I mixed up the wrong combination of passing list of args vs single string and using shell=True or not. Probably I was seeing this docker help menu because docker was the first (and only?) arg being handled whatever I have as next words in my list.

Finally, thank you for the security considerations. You would rather advise me to use python libs like docker-py to interract with the docker daemon? It would be another python dependency to install but not a big deal, would make the code portable on all my platforms (own PC and GH runner).

I think you're fine using subprocess to call out to the docker cli. I do think you should take @DavidMaze's suggestion and avoid the use of shell=True, and instead rely on Python to read the output and write it to a file.
